# Setting up BizTalk 2013 R2 image in Azure VM

Tags: azure, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I have followed the below URL to create the BizTalk image in Azure VM.

[Create & Configure BizTalk Server 2013 VM in Windows Azure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/teekamg/2013/03/13/create-configure-biztalk-server-2013-vm-in-windows-azure/)

After creating the VM I can see the BizTalk server installed in VM. While configuring the BizTalk server I gave the server name, username and password for creating the databases. At that i got an error as below:

[image: error message]

Do we need a seperate VM for SQL SERVER ?

In that case SQL SERVER will not will be installed while selecting BizTalk2013R2 image?

How can I install both SQL SERVER and BizTalk server in single VM?

Comment: Is SQL Server running?  Can you connect with Mgmt Studio?

Comment: Itseems like SQL server is not installed when we choose BT2013R2 image in azure VM. we have to maually install SQL. I thought SQL also will be installed while selecting BT2013R2 image

Comment: Exactly which Image did you choose?  IIRC, only the MSDN Developer images come with the full stack.  The paid Images expect a separate, paid, SQL Server VM.

Comment: I chooses "BizTalk Server 2013 R2 Standard Image" [Basic Tier (A0)).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have not completed Post-installation Steps for BizTalk and SQL Server 2012. Solution to your problem is to enable MSDTC and enable TCPIP and namepipe in SQL Server Management Studio.

For more details refer to this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248704.aspx

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

If you chose BizTalk Server Enterprise or Standard, then no, those are the paid instances and do not include SQL Server.  You must provision a paid VM of SQL Server to use with those BizTalk VM's.

Only the MSDN Developer editions of BizTalk VM's include the full stack, including SQL Server and Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi John, I have already created BizTalk 2013 R2 Standard Image (basic tier). Can i Install manually to download SQL express/developer edition and install it in same BizTalk VM and run it for time being instead of provision of seperate SQL Server VM Image.  ??

Comment: This is very, very important: are you trying to use a Developer (MSDN) BizTalk Image or fully licensed (PAID) BizTalk VM?

Comment: Hi John, I am not using MSDN (BizTalk Developer Image). I am using "BizTalk 2013 R2 Standard" Image VM from Gallery (hourly price PAID (Size A1-Core/Basic Tier)). After installing this Image, I am able to see the BizTalk Installed in the VM. No SQL Installed . so my doubt is like, Do we really need to choose SQL Image in another VM as like BizTalk Image in azure portal?  OR is it fine to download free sql expression/developer edition and manually install it in the Same BizTalk VM itself?

Comment: You situation is still a bit confusing.  You do expect to PAY for this BizTalk instance, correct?  SQL Server Express IS NOT SUPPORTED, so that is not an option.  Also, you cannot use SQL Developer (free) with BizTalk Server Standard (paid).  Both must be either DEV/MSDN or Paid.

Comment: If this is a paid instance of BizTalk for Production use, you can up/download paid SQL Server media and install SQL Server locally.  Your only option is per-cpu license.  If you want pay-by-use, you need to provision a SQL Server VM.

Comment: Actually It is not for production Use, this is for doing POC before starting the actual work.Thats why I am thinking why should I provision a separate SQL Server VM, Instead I can download the sql server and install it in a same BizTalk Image. Am I correct? please suggest.

Comment: Then you should be using an MSDN image with the full stack.

Comment: I am little confused. Actually I wanted to do one POC for BizTalk 2013 R2 in Azure. So I used azure subscription and when I verified the BizTalk Images from Gallery, there is no Dev/MSDN BizTalk Image. Only two BizTalk Images(standard/enterprise). so I was choosed Standard Image and installed. Now I need to Install SQL for configuring BizTalk. There bit confusion. Can we install SQL in same BizTalk Image or need to choose separate VM as like BizTalk Image?. If BizTalk and SQL is in separate VM, then do I need to do any additional configuration for connecting SQL from BizTalk VM?.please suggest

Comment: You have to associate your MSDN Subscription to you Azure Subscription for the MSDN Gallery to appear.  If you don't have MSDN, you have to use paid versions in one of the configurations I've already listed above.

Comment: Thanks John for the detailed information. So Either I have to choose MSDN subscription to get a full stack of BizTalk Developer edition which includes all dependent software (installed by default). Otherwise, need to choose paid instances BizTalk (STD/Enterprise), then must provision a paid another VM of SQL Server to use with those BizTalk VM's. We can't install SQL server in the Same BizTalk paid instances VM. please confirm my above understanding. I will check with my admin department whether we have any MSDN subscription already available before proceeding.

Comment: Please read my previous comments.  Question already answered.